# What is exclusion constraint in PostgreSQL? What is the according term (and sample SQL script) in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, exclusion-constraint

I read a book

[image]

Exclusion constraint

```sql
CREATE TABLE movies
(
    Title TEXT,
    Copies INTEGER
);

ALTER TABLE movies ADD EXCLUDE (title WITH=, copies WITH=);
```

What is the meaning of *Exclusion constraints*? What is the according term (and sample SQL script) in Microsoft SQL Server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the meaning of Exclusion constraints?

That's a special type of constraints, that is defined as a series of comparaison on table columns. It guaranties that there cannot be two different rows for which the comparisons are all true.

In the (oversimplified) example that is presented in the book, the constraint prevents two different rows to have the same `title` *and* the same `copies`.

Exclusion constraints are very powerful; they have a flexible syntax, that can accomodate much more complex cases that what is demonstrated in your book. A typical example is to ensure that, given a table with two timestamp columns, there is no overlap in the timestamp ranges across rows.

> What is the according term (and sample SQL script) in Microsoft SQL Server?

I don't think that such feature exists in SQL Server. It has check constraints, but that does not offer the same range of functionality as Postgres' exclusion constraints.

Comment: Can you show few lines of SQL for easy-to-understand? An example for valid data, An another example for invalid data. I still don't understand.

Comment: @DoNhuVy: for your example, you can't have two rows with the same `title` and `copies`. Rows with the same `title` and different `copies` are allowed, as well as rows with the same `copies` and different `title`.

Comment: For the example, couldn't you implement it with a composite unique constraint?

Comment: @BenThul This example doesn't accurately describe the usage of exclusion constraint. Yes, in this example composite unique constraint would be better. However, for cases where I want to check against a range like start date and end date, exclude constraint would be the choice.

Comment: @Vaulstein - In my comment _from three years ago_, I was speaking to the OPs question which I took to mean "how does one implement the specific constraint `EXCLUDE (title WITH=, copies WITH=)`. While I appreciate that, generally speaking, EXCLUDE constraints can be more expressive than that, that's not the point.

Comment: Yes I understand. Wanted to just share a better example of Exclude constraints for anyone who reads the comments in the future